# Customizing Number of Page Links Rendered With will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm using the will_paginate gem for my Rails project and it's working beautifully.  Unfortunately, on paginated result sets with a larger number of pages, the link section is too wide.  Instead of:

`« Previous 1 2 … 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 … 18 19 Next »`

I would like to show:

`« Previous 1 2 … 5 6 7 8 9 … 18 19 Next »`

How can I reduce the number of page links being rendered?  I looked at the will_paginate docs on github but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks!
Moe

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `:inner_window` option:

```
<%= will_paginate stuff, :inner_window => 2 %>
```

You can see all the options [right here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb).